# Collapsing Results of a Union in a Postgres View

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, union, greatest-n-per-group

### Basic Question

Is there a way in Postgres 9.2 to create a view that aggregates data from two tables, with a bit of logic involved?

The logic we need is:

1. Data in one table takes precedence over the other
2. Subsequent rows with the same `key` (a combination of multiple fields) overwrite previous ones.
3. Rows with a status of `D` delete any preceding rows for a given 'key'.

### More Details and Example

I have 2 schemas in a Postgres database. They each have identical tables and columns, but different data.  One is for official data, and one is for proposed changes.

Note: I'm sure there is a better way, but this is a legacy setup and can't be changed.  This is a very simplified, fictionalized example, but shows the situation and result I need.

So we have a table of characteristics, describing a widget. There is only one of each type of data in the official data (a widget will have one size, one color, etc).

Proposed changes, once approved, change the official data. There may be multiple pending changes for a given type of data.

#### `official` schema

```
CREATE TABLE characteristics (
    widget_id      integer NOT NULL,
    variation_id   integer NOT NULL,
    value          varchar(10),
    action_date    date,
    status         char(1)
);
```

Sample data in `official.characteristics`:

```
1,1,GI Joe,12/25/2012,C
1,2,Green,12/25/2012,C
1,3,M,12/25/2012,C
1,4,Plastic,12/25/2012,C
2,1,GI Joe,12/25/2012,C
2,2,Green,12/25/2012,C
2,3,L,12/25/2012,C
2,4,Plastic,12/25/2012,C
```

So we have 2 widgets, one is medium, green and plastic.  One is large, green, and plastic.

#### `proposed` schema

```
CREATE TABLE characteristics (
    widget_id      integer NOT NULL,
    variation_id   integer NOT NULL,
    value          varchar(10),
    action_date    date,
    status         char(1)
);
```

Sample data in `proposed.characteristics`:

```
1,2,Blue,2/22/2013,C
1,4,Plastic,2/22/2013,D
2,2,Purple,2/10/2013,C
2,2,Green,2/22/2013,D
2,3,XL,2/22/2013,C
```

If we want to see what the result of all the proposed changes would be, we can query both tables, with newer data replacing old, or D rows deleting any previous ones.

```
SELECT
  'o' as src,
  lpad(widget_id::text,4,'0'::text) || '_' || lpad(variation_id::text,4,'0'::text) as key,
  *
FROM
  proposed.characteristics
ORDER BY
  key ASC,
  action_date::date ASC
```

The 2nd query is the same, but on the other table and with 'p' as the src.

Using PHP, I can query each table, official first, proposed changes second, and put the data into an array with the `key` (`widget_id || '_' || variation_id`) as key. Any new rows overwrite old ones. If the `status` is `D` (for delete), then the row with the key is deleted (though a subsequent proposed change may re-add it).

So for the data above we would end up with:

```
o,0001_0001,1,1,GI Joe,12/25/2012,C
p,0001_0002,1,2,Blue,2/22/2013,C
o,0001_0003,1,3,M,12/25/2012,C
o,0002_0001,1,1,GI Joe,12/25/2012,C
p,0002_0003,2,3,XL,2/22/2013,C
o,0002_0004,2,4,Plastic,12/25/2012,C
```

#### Summary

Is there a way I can create a view where I can directly query the results above?
And still have the `D` for delete work, and newer changes overwrite previous changes or official data?

Comment: `They each have identical tables and columns` .. so I assume th column should be named `action_date` in both tables? Also: Postgres version? And last row of your example output should start with `o` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Good catch, right on both accounts.  Fixed, and added Postgres version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Assuming current version PostgreSQL 9.2 for lack of information.</sup>

One way to do it is a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) with a `UNION ALL` of both tables, and get the last valid version for each widget with a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) anti-semi-join:

```
CREATE VIEW my_viw AS
WITH x AS (
   SELECT 'o' as src, * FROM official.characteristics
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'p' as src, * FROM proposed.characteristics
   )
SELECT lpad(widget_id::text, 4, '0')
       || '_' || lpad(variation_id::text, 4, '0') AS key, * -- pick columns
FROM   x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM x y
   WHERE  y.widget_id = x.widget_id
   AND    y.variation_id = x.variation_id
   AND    y.action_date > x.action_date
   )
AND   (status <> 'D' OR status IS NULL)
ORDER  BY widget_id, variation_id
```

Returns the result you outlined, except for the mistake I pointed out in the comment.

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/17151/2)

#### Step by step

1. Fetch all rows from both tables with a simple and fast `UNION ALL` in a CTE
2. Exclude rows, where a later row for the same (widget_id, variation_id) exists with `NOT EXISTS`
3. Exclude rows with `status = 'D'`.
4. ORDER BY and synthesize key from `widget_id, variation_id`.

#### Major points

- It's most likely faster to operate with the original columns `widget_id, variation_id` and only synthesize the `key` in the final `SELECT`. Less code, easier to index.
- Use a CTE, because the result is needed in two places.
- The columns `status` should be defined `NOT NULL`, would make the WHERE conditions simpler.
- A multicolumn index like the following on both tables might help performance. Not sure it can be used after the `UNION ALL`. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see.

  ```
  CREATE INDEX characteristics_mult_idx
  ON official.characteristics (widget_id, variation_id, action_date DESC)
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I'm leaving the office shortly, but will test it Monday.